# Django on Pythonanywhere IOError/RuntimeError

Tags: javascript, css, django, static, pythonanywhere

I had my css/js up and running [pythonanywhere using django](https://www.pythonanywhere.com). I add more features and then uploaded them using github. I saw that they worked on pythonanywhere then I went home. Later on in the day I opened my site and saw that the css/js is not loading. However, the icon in the same folder is loading.
I tried deleting my project and re-cloning it. I also tried just deleting the site and re-setting it up with no results. I recently got these errors:

```
2015-03-16 10:36:03,205 :IOError: write error
2015-03-16 10:36:03,205 :RuntimeError: generator ignored GeneratorExit
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are just an indication that the client disconnected while the response was going out. Usually it means that the user went to a different page, or reloaded or something like that.